# npm/gulp-babel: target works everywhere BUT on my machine, what's wrong?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, babeljs, gulp-babel

This is driving me crazy. I am in charge of the development and need to do merging of branches, but exactly on my machine only something is not working.

I have several times removed `node_modules` and run `npm install`, and even completely cloned the repo and setup everything again, and always I will get the same issue.

Someone merged code with ES6, so we need to transpile it, because the minifier plugin does not work with ES6 code.

So we use `gulp-babel`

```
var
          gulp  = require('gulp')
         //more requires
        , babel = require('gulp-babel')

var libs_js = [
   //list of javascripts
]

gulp.task('js-build', function () {
  gulp.src(libs_js)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(running_task != 'js-build' ? _bypass() : tap(function(f) { f.contents = new Buffer('document.write(\'<script src="' + f.path.replace(process.cwd(), '') 
        .replaceAll('\\','/') // fix paths for windows
      + '"><\/script>\')') })) 
    .pipe(concat(pkg.name + '.js', {newLine: '\n;'}))
    .pipe(babel({presets: ['es2015'],compact: false}))
    .pipe(running_task == 'js-build' ? _bypass() : uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('[' + new Date + '] js compiled')
    })  
});

//other gulp targets

gulp.task('prod', ['js-build', 'css', 'sass', 'assets', 'libs']);
```

running `gulp prod`, for everyone it works, BUT for me, I get:

```
...
[Wed Oct 26 2016 22:05:51 GMT-0500 (COT)] asset completedd

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Couldn't find preset "latest" relative to directory "/home/me/prj/src"
    at /home/me/prj/src/frontend/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:299:19
```

First, why complaining about `"latest"`, if in the code we use `es2015`. I went and ran everything on an other computer, where it worked, and I found something astonishing:

On my machine:

```
>$ npm list | grep babel
├─┬ babel-preset-es2015@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants@6.8.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions@6.8.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions@6.8.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-template@6.16.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-define-map@6.18.0
│ │ ├── babel-helper-function-name@6.18.0
│ │ ├── babel-helper-optimise-call-expression@6.18.0
│ │ ├── babel-helper-replace-supers@6.18.0
│ │ └── babel-messages@6.8.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-properties@6.8.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring@6.18.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-duplicate-keys@6.8.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of@6.18.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-name@6.9.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-literals@6.8.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs@6.18.0
│ │ └── babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-systemjs@6.18.0
│ │ └── babel-helper-hoist-variables@6.18.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd@6.18.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-object-super@6.8.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters@6.18.0
│ │ ├── babel-helper-call-delegate@6.18.0
│ │ └── babel-helper-get-function-arity@6.18.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties@6.18.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread@6.8.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-sticky-regex@6.8.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-helper-regex@6.18.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals@6.8.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-typeof-symbol@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-unicode-regex@6.11.0
│ └─┬ babel-plugin-transform-regenerator@6.16.1
├─┬ gulp-babel@6.1.2
│ ├─┬ babel-core@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.16.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-generator@6.18.0
│ │ ├── babel-helpers@6.16.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-register@6.18.0
```

On the other one:

```
$ npm list | grep babel
├─┬ babel-preset-es2015@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants@6.8.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions@6.8.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions@6.8.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-template@6.16.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.18.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.16.0
│ │ │ ├── babel-messages@6.8.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-define-map@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-function-name@6.18.0
│ │ │ └── babel-helper-get-function-arity@6.18.0
│ │ ├── babel-helper-optimise-call-expression@6.18.0
│ │ ├── babel-helper-replace-supers@6.18.0
│ │ ├── babel-messages@6.8.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-template@6.16.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.18.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.16.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-properties@6.8.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-define-map@6.18.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-function-name@6.18.0
│ │ │ │ ├── babel-helper-get-function-arity@6.18.0
│ │ │ │ └─┬ babel-traverse@6.18.0
│ │ │ │   ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.16.0
│ │ │ │   ├── babel-messages@6.8.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-template@6.16.0
│ │   ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.18.0
│ │   │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.16.0
│ │   │ ├── babel-messages@6.8.0
│ │   ├─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring@6.18.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-duplicate-keys@6.8.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of@6.18.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-name@6.9.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-function-name@6.18.0
│ │ │ ├── babel-helper-get-function-arity@6.18.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-template@6.16.0
│ │ │ └─┬ babel-traverse@6.18.0
│ │ │   ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.16.0
│ │ │   ├── babel-messages@6.8.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-literals@6.8.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-template@6.16.0
│ │   ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.18.0
│ │   │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.16.0
│ │   │ ├── babel-messages@6.8.0
│ │   ├─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs@6.18.0
│ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-template@6.16.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.18.0
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.16.0
│ │ │ │ ├── babel-messages@6.8.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-systemjs@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-hoist-variables@6.18.0
│ │ │ └─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-template@6.16.0
│ │   ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.18.0
│ │   │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.16.0
│ │   │ ├── babel-messages@6.8.0
│ │   ├─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-template@6.16.0
│ │   ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.18.0
│ │   │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.16.0
│ │   │ ├── babel-messages@6.8.0
│ │   ├─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-object-super@6.8.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-replace-supers@6.18.0
│ │ │ ├── babel-helper-optimise-call-expression@6.18.0
│ │ │ ├── babel-messages@6.8.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-template@6.16.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.18.0
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.16.0
│ │ │ └─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-call-delegate@6.18.0
│ │ │ └── babel-helper-hoist-variables@6.18.0
│ │ ├── babel-helper-get-function-arity@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-template@6.16.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.18.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.16.0
│ │ │ ├── babel-messages@6.8.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread@6.8.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-sticky-regex@6.8.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-regex@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals@6.8.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-typeof-symbol@6.18.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-unicode-regex@6.11.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-regex@6.18.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ └─┬ babel-plugin-transform-regenerator@6.16.1
│   ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│   ├─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
├─┬ gulp-babel@6.1.2
│ ├─┬ babel-core@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.16.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-generator@6.18.0
│ │ ├── babel-helpers@6.16.0
│ │ ├── babel-messages@6.8.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-register@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.18.0
│ │ ├── babel-template@6.16.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.18.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-types@6.18.0
```

They are different!!!!
**How the heck is this even possible**???
I mean I used the exact same commands on both machines, `package.json` is the same for everybody, and no different command other than `npm install` and `gulp prod` has been run (I even used gulp from `node_modules/.bin/gulp`)

The only things I could think of:
- There's something binary which could cause problems
- node or npm versions? Using node 5.1 here
- Some concurrency issue, as my PC is using SSD storage?

For reference, here `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "Proj",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "", 
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-postbuild": "bower install && gulp prod"
  },  
  "author": "", 
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1"
  },  
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.7.9",
    "colors": "^1.1.2",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "es6-promise": "^3.2.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "fb-watchman": "^1.9.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-tap": "^0.1.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "request": "^2.74.0",
    "uglify-js": "^2.7.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your package.json

"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ]
},

or to an existing .babelrc if you have one

Comment: Hey thanks Mark, this has been so troublesome for us that we had to revert pull requests in order to get us further. I can't reproduce this anymore now, so I can't accept your answer as I can't verify, but I'll upvote :) Thanks!